# angular 4 async pipe is not working

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use async pipe but there is no data being displayed.  I'm logging the data that is coming from the server and it shows up fine in the console. But for some reason I can't get the async to work.

shift.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Shift } from '../shift/shift';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ShiftService {

  constructor(private shift:Shift, private httpClient:HttpClient
              ) { this.checkShiftStatus();}

  checkShiftStatus():Promise<Shift>{
    this.httpClient.get<Shift>('http://localhost:8080/shift/isopen')
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.shift = data;
        console.log(this.shift);
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Something went wrong while trying to check the shift!');
      });
    return Promise.resolve(this.shift);
  }
}
```

shift.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Shift } from './shift';
import { ShiftService } from '../services/shift.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shift',
  templateUrl: './shift.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shift.component.css']
})
export class ShiftComponent implements OnInit {
  isShiftOpen:Promise<boolean>;

  shiftLive:Promise<Shift>;

  constructor(private shiftService: ShiftService, public shift:Shift) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isShiftOpen = this.getShift().then(shift => this.shift.active = shift.active);
    this.shiftLive = this.shiftService.checkShiftStatus();
  }

  getShift(){
    return this.shiftService.checkShiftStatus().then(shift => this.shift = shift);
  }
}
```

shift.component.html

```
<md-grid-list *ngIf="isShiftOpen | async" cols="2" rowHeight="100px">
  <md-grid-tile>
      <button md-raised-button [disabled]='isShiftOpen' color="primary">Open Shift</button>
      <button md-raised-button [disabled]='!isShiftOpen' color="warn">Close Shift</button>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>

<md-card class="card">
  <md-card-title>
    Shift Stats:
  </md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>

    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
<!-- <div *ngIf="(shiftLive | async)?.notnull; else loading"> -->
<div *ngIf="shiftLive | async">
    <p> Shift status: {{ shiftLive.active }} </p>

    <p> Tickets Sold: {{ shiftLive.totalNumberOfTicketsSold }} </p>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading Data...</ng-template>
```

The buttons don't even show up even though the service is providing with the value of true.  I do get the div to show up but there is no value for shiftLive.active, or the shiftLive.totalNumberOfTicketsSold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're resolving the promise before the result comes in asynchronously and promises only resolve once. You need to return the unresolved promise and wait for the result to come in and then resolve your promise, like this:

```
checkShiftStatus():Promise<Shift>{
  let promise = new Promise<Shift>();
  this.httpClient.get<Shift>('http://localhost:8080/shift/isopen')
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.shift = data;
      promise.resolve(this.shift);
      console.log(this.shift);
    },
    error => {
      console.error('Something went wrong while trying to check the shift!');
    });
  return promise;
}
```

And then your use of promises is all wrong in your component.  You're defining and setting variables that are outside the scope.  The async pipe handles all of this for you.

or better yet, don't use the promise at all since observables are way better

service:

```
// just return the observable stream and don't subscribe, let async handle your subscriptions
checkShiftStatus():Observable<Shift>{
  return this.httpClient.get<Shift>('http://localhost:8080/shift/isopen')
    .do((data) => {
      // you really shouldn't do this. statefulness like this is a sign of bad design
      this.shift = data;
      console.log(this.shift);
    }).catch(err => {
     console.log('make sure to handle this error');
     Observable.throw(err);
   });
}
```

component:

```
// only set this once so that we don't make the same http call over and over, we have all the data we need here (the $ syntax is standard for denoting an observable)
this.shiftLive$ = this.shiftService.checkShiftStatus();
```

template:

```
//only use async once to avoid multiple subscriptions, and declare it "as" whatever you want, and then you have access to it throughout the template, you can still use your loading template as you want.
<ng-container *ngIf="shiftLive$ | async as shiftLive; else loading"> 
<md-grid-list *ngIf="shiftLive.active" cols="2" rowHeight="100px">
  <md-grid-tile>
      <button md-raised-button [disabled]='shiftLive.active' color="primary">Open Shift</button>
      <button md-raised-button [disabled]='!shiftLive.active' color="warn">Close Shift</button>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>

<md-card class="card">
  <md-card-title>
    Shift Stats:
  </md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>

  </md-card-content>
</md-card>

<div>
    <p> Shift status: {{ shiftLive.active }} </p>

    <p> Tickets Sold: {{ shiftLive.totalNumberOfTicketsSold }} </p>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading Data...</ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I made your suggested changes and tried to run the program.  But ended up with an error stating ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ShiftComponent.html:18)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] .
In the service I'm using this.httpClient.get<Shift>('http://localhost:8080/shift/isopen'); only this much code for now.  Not even trying to catch the error. Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: after including *ngIf="shiftLive$ | async as shiftLive; else loading in the div section it started working fine.  But you are right about it making multiple http calls to the server.

Comment: You need to only subscribe once as I showed you. There is no need to split that observable stream into two calls. All the needed information is in the same call

Comment: Material causes the issue.  After moving the div inside of the md-grid I only had to make one http call.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you return an undefined value in your checkShiftStatus method from shift.service.ts

```
return Promise.resolve(this.shift);
```

You should refactor your method this way :

```
checkShiftStatus(): Observable<Shift>{
  return this.httpClient.get<Shift>('http://localhost:8080/shift/isopen')
}
```

And then do something with your data in the shift.component.ts and shift.component.html :

```
export class ShiftComponent implements OnInit {

  shift: any;

  constructor(private shiftService: ShiftService, public shift:Shift) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getShift();
  }

  getShift(): void {
    this.shiftService.checkShiftStatus()
      .subscribe(shift => this.shift = shift);
  }

  isActive(): boolean {
    return this.shift && this.shift.active;
  }

  ticketsSold(): number {
    return this.shift ? this.shift.totalNumberOfTicketsSold : 0;
  }
}
```

---

```
<md-grid-list *ngIf="isActive()" cols="2" rowHeight="100px">
  <md-grid-tile>
    <button md-raised-button [disabled]='isActive()' color="primary">Open Shift</button>
    <button md-raised-button [disabled]='!isActive()' color="warn">Close Shift</button>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>

<md-card class="card">
  <md-card-title>
    Shift Stats:
  </md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
<!-- <div *ngIf="shift?.notnull; else loading"> -->
<div *ngIf="shift">
  <p> Shift status: {{ isActive() }} </p>
  <p> Tickets Sold: {{ ticketsSold() }} </p>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading Data...</ng-template>
```

Comment: async pipe is the cleaner, safer and preferred approach to subscribing to observables