# Can not use Async Pipe RXJS - ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I can not display my observables directly when I want to use the Async Pipe.
I can do without the pipe async, and it works. My comment code works well, but I would really like to use the Async Pipe for Angular and unsubscribe alone.

user.service

```
  public newsfeed: BehaviorSubject<MessageUser> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

reloadNewsFeed(): Observable<MessageUser> {
      return this.http.get<MessageUser>('api/user/newsfeed').pipe(
        tap((x: MessageUser)=>{
        this.newsfeed.next(x)
      }), switchMap(()=>{
        return this.newsfeed
      }))
  };
```

newsfeed.component.ts

```
//public lesMessage2; 
public lesMessages:Observable<MessageUser>

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
  ) { }

 ngOnInit() {

  // It does not work
    this.lesMessages = this.userService.reloadNewsFeed()

  // OK that works
  //   this.subMessage = this.userService.reloadNewsFeed().subscribe((user: MessageUser)=>{
  //   console.log(user);
  //   this.lesMessage2 = user;
  // }, (err)=>{
  //   console.log(err);
  // })
  }
```

newsfeed.component.html

```
<span *ngIf="lesMessage | async; let user">
<p>Iterer sur mon Subjects : <strong> {{ user.message }} </strong> </p>
</span>
```

Comment: I think you need to return unresolved promise, Hope this link will help you,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434037/angular-4-async-pipe-is-not-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular 4 async pipe is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434037/angular-4-async-pipe-is-not-working)

Comment: on my app.component.html >>
Object Object, Object Object, Object Object, Object Object, Object Object, Object Object, Object Object, Object Object [object Object], [object Object]
and on my console.log
(I do not have an error)

Comment: Why are you using the BehaviorSubject and not returning the observable directly?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that in TS file you have property named as `this.lesMessages` but in template you try to subscribe to "lesMessage" (should be lesMessages). Try to change your current string:

```
... *ngIf="lesMessages | async" ...
```